# how to set value to property of custom imageview?

Tags: java, android, custom-view

I have a custom Imageview class like below. I have a field called timeInterval which I pass it in constructor, but in onDraw it's value is 0. What is the proper way to pass this? also I don't know if I can pass it dynamically as attribute.

```
public class ProgressBarView extends AppCompatImageView {

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private int mTimeInterval;
    private int mColor;
    private int[] mLocations = new int[2];

    public ProgressBarView(Context context, int timeInterval) {
        super(context);
        mTimeInterval = timeInterval;
        init(null);
    }

    public ProgressBarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrst) {
        super(context, attrst);
        init(attrst);
    }

    public ProgressBarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs == null) {
            return;
        }
        TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ProgressBarView);
        mColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.ProgressBarView_overlay_color, Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void updatePainting() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(this::invalidate, mTimeInterval / 360);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        if (mTimeInterval == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int seconds = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int mStartAngel = (int) (((float) (seconds % (mTimeInterval / 1000))
                / (mTimeInterval / 1000)) * 360);
        final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(mColor);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setAlpha(-50);
        getLocationOnScreen(mLocations);
        int radius = getWidth() / 2;
        float centreX = this.getX() + radius;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            canvas.drawArc(centreX - radius, centreX - radius, centreX + radius, centreX + radius, 0, mStartAngel, true, paint);
        } else {
            final RectF oval = new RectF();
            oval.set(centreX - radius, centreX - radius, centreX + radius, centreX + radius);
            canvas.drawArc(oval, 0, mStartAngel, true, paint);
        }
        updatePainting();
    }
}
```

I instantiate it like this:

```
mProgressBarView = new ProgressBarView(getContext(), timeInterval);
```

Comment: Is that the only place `ProgressBarView` is being instantiated? Do you perhaps have it in your layout somewhere, too?

Comment: How are you creating your `ProgressBarView`, programmatically or by xml layout?

Comment: It got fixed, It was my bad I had it in my xml and I was instantiating it again programatically, thank you for your help. @MikeM.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about "this"

```
public ProgressBarView(Context context, int timeInterval) {
    super(context);
    this.mTimeInterval = timeInterval;
    init(null);
}
```

Comment: No it is not the problem.

Comment: Yes, I see now. So, did you launch your app in debug mode with stop points?